# Возможно ли превратить dict в string?

Tags: lua

На пример у меня есть дикт:

```
myDict = {
    "prikol" = 1,
    "prikolchik" = "prikolnie"
}
```

И мне нужно превратить его в подобную строку:

```
"{\"prikol\" = 1, \"prikolchik\" = \"prikolnie\"}"
```

Возможно ли это?

Comment: Именно в такую строку? Синтаксис похож на json, но там между ключами и значениями символ ":"

Comment: @gil9red, Именно такую, это строка сохраниться в базе и потом я это строку возьму оттуда и обратно в dict превращу

Comment: Тогда учтите, что у строки, что вы получите не будет экранирования кавычек, т.к. эта вещь применяется исключительно для литералов строк, чтобы не было проблем при представлении. Т.е. у вас получится строка `{"prikol" = 1, "prikolchik" = "prikolnie"}` и это нормально

Comment: Я подозреваю что можно просто сделать новую строку `"{"` и просто проходить по всем элементам этого dict'a добавляя например `"\"".ключ.""\" = "..значение..","`, и в конце закрыть это всё просто добавив `"}"`

Comment: Вот тут есть по вашей задаче: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9168058/5909792, но я бы поискал способ сохранять в строку json :)